# Configuration and initialization of spice-vdagentd

Tags: spice

I just installed `spice-vdagent` inside one of my VMs but it seems that spice-vdagentd is not currently running. Checking its systemd unit status shows some error about `/var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagentd.pid` not existing. Since /run is reset during each start it does not make sense to manually create this folder, where should I configure spice-vdagentd such that this folder gets created automatically?

Comment: The error does not mention `/run`, but `/var/run`, which is not cleared when restarting. Just create the missing directory with `sudo mkdir /var/run/spice-vdagentd` and try to start again: `sudo service spice-vdagent start`

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu 17.04)  /var/run is just a symlink to /run

Comment: You are right. What if starting servive spice-vdagent manually?

Answer (score 2):

I've been running Ubuntu 18.04 for some years, and I've just started seeing this problem. Perhaps some update has broken things.

Every time I update packages I see this error.

Here's my fix:

```
# sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/spice-vdagentd.service
```

Find this line:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagent-sock
```

and replace it with these lines:

```
#ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagent-sock
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/bin/rm -f /var/run/spice-vdagentd/spice-vdagent-sock ; /bin/mkdir -p /var/run/spice-vdagentd'
```

In other words, comment out the original `ExecStartPre` (always good practice to leave the original code there), then put in a new `ExecStartPre` which does 2 things:

1. Remove the socket file (if it exists) - this is what the original did.
2. Make the `/var/run/spice-vdagentd` directory if it doesn't exist.

Now, save your changes and do this to start the daemon:

```
# sudo systemctl start spice-vdagent
```